# Configure JRE for sonar-runner in IntelliJ

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, sonarqube

I have a remote SonarQube server running (version 5.0.1) and the SonarQube Plugin for IntelliJ (IntelliJ Version 13 Ultimate) installed.

Now I want to analyze my source code within in IntelliJ using this plugin. The problem is that I get a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`-Error. Furthermore IntelliJ claims at the end of the error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error status [command: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.6\jre\jre\bin\java.exe ...`

How can I change the JRE version IntelliJ uses to call the sonar-runner? Normally I work with Java 8 and I would like to use Java 8 for the sonar-runner too.

Some background information:

My operating system is Windows 7 Enterprise and the JAVA_HOME variable is set to the desired Java Version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for myself described in this post: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827547-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

1. Add a Windows environment variable called IDEA_JDK and set it to the desired **64-bit** JDK version.
2. Start the **64-bit** version of IntelliJ with idea64.exe